# RSpec matching response

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec-rails

I am using Ruby on Rails 5 and Rspec.

My test is like

`expect(json_response['data']['body']).to match(/'["can't be blank"]'/)`

I am getting error

`expected ["can't be blank"] to match /'["can't be blank"]'/`

I was wondering, how to fix it ? Hope it is clear.

Comment: did you tried to change expectation like expect(json_response['data']['body']).to match_array(["can't be blank"]) see whether its passing test

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading the test failure, the JSON response returns an array with a string in it: `["can't be blank"]`. Seems like a fine use case for testing equality directly:

```rb
expect(json_response['data']['body']).to eq(["can't be blank"])
```

`match_array` will work, but it "disregards differences in the ordering between the actual and expected array." As an array with one item only, that feature isn't necessary here.

[contains_exactly/match_array docs](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/3-8/docs/built-in-matchers/contain-exactly-matcher)

Answer (score 1):

Try the [`match_array`](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/rspec/rspec-expectations/RSpec%2FMatchers:match_array) helper method.

```
expect(json_response['data']['body']).to match_array(["can't be blank"])
```